# How to check if a file from a list contains something , in makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to check if all the files that have a specific name have in them a string , if not to report them . I wrote this sequence and tried multiple some others, but I don't know how to access the contain of a file from list.

```
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name 'mod.mak')#here I take the list of targeted files (this works fine)
$(foreach File, Files,
$(if $(grep -q "aaabbb" "$File"),,@echo "WARNING Missing sequence")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues with your script.

First of all, you [need some rule/target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Contents). For your example we can make a [`PHONY` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) `test`. Second, to iterate over values in `SOURCES`, you need to [reference it](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference) as `$(SOURCES)`. Similarly for `$(file)` in call to `grep`. Also, `make`'s [`if`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions) is interpreting value, not exit code, so you shouldn't silence `grep`.

This will do it:

```
.PHONY: test

SOURCES := $(shell find "$(SOURCEDIR)" -name 'mod.mak')

test:
    $(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(if $(shell grep "aaabbb" "$(file)"),,@echo "WARNING Missing sequence in $(file)"))
```